# Octave on MacOS and how to install a package?

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave

I'm completely lost, I installed brew on my mac and installed octave with brew, but when I try to install package inside octave-gui prompt 'pkg install package_name' im gettin' ar error.

```
error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied:
   symbolic needs octave >= 4.2.0
```

Mine version is 4.0.3 and it is the latest octave available on MacOS, any suggestions?

Comment: Current version of Octave on Homebrew is 6.3.0. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/octave

Answer (score 1):

You should start with updating homebrew itself:

```
brew update
```

After that you will be able to update octave:

```
brew upgrade octave
```